# Which Cuda version is compatible for Tensorflow 1.8.0?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

I'm using python 2.7 and Keras 2.1.4.
Out of the following versions (cuda/10.0 ,10.1, 10.2, 11.0, 11.1, 11.1.0, 11.1.1, 11.2, 11.2.2, 9.0, 9.1, 9.2) which version can I use for Tensorflow 1.8.0?
Is there any specific documentation? where I could read more about these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this table](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) to check compatibilities. For version 1.8.0, it is `cuda/9`.